# Which user name do I need to remotely log into my Mac?

Tags: sharing, user-account

My username in the Mac login screen ("My Name", there is a space) doesn't match the one in Finder and terminal ("anothername"). Which one is my real username? The reason I'm asking is that I want to share media files over my home network, and when I was trying to access the media from another computer, it ask me for username and password. I don't know which one is my username I only know the password. I tried both and neither worked. Always says wrong username or password. I'm sure I know my password because that's how I login to my Mac. Could there be a third username? I'm completely lost.

Comment: possible duplicate of [username different in Terminal and System Preferences](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28462/username-different-in-terminal-and-system-preferences)

Comment: (although it looks like there is a second question here of "Why can't I connect to my computer from another computer?")

Answer (score 2):

Either works. You have a short-name and a long name. Here's a great article about it.

http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201548