# How to change username that shows in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, user-account

In the Terminal, my username shows up as `keegankuhn` (`firstnamelastname`) when I want it to show `kk` (`firstinitiallastinitial`). (I want this to actually change and not just *show* something else!) How would I do this from my own account?

Comment: The questions is different from https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28462/username-different-in-terminal-and-system-preferences, but it provides an acceptable answer.

Comment: I'd also like if I could do it from my own account.

Comment: I've found an answer, but for some reason can't post my own answer. Here's the answer: 1. Open System Preferences. 2. Select Users & Groups. 3. Click the lock to make changes and enter your password. 4. Right click or two-finger click on your user and select Advanced Options. Finally, change Account Name and reboot.

Comment: Were you able to log in and access your files after the reboot?

Comment: @patrix Yes, I was.

Comment: The answer then easily fits the original question as well, feel free to post it there.